# How to use LinearGradient in React Native ART?

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-native

I would like to use React Native ART to create some animated SVG graphs. My graph needs an linear gradient, I see that React Native ART seems to have it implemented, but I have no idea on how to use it.

Does anyone know or can figure it out by looking at the javascript here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART.js

I am not that good with Javascript yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [this post](http://react-china.org/t/react-native-art-path-lineargradient/9919)

You can declare the LinearGradient as such:

```
  let colors = [ "red", "green",  "blue", ];
  let linearGradient = new LinearGradient(colors, 0, 20, 0, 280);
```

Then use it in your Shape for example:

```
<Shape d={path} fill={linearGradient} />
```

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be support for offset % such as in d3js.

Comment: Just wrong,it will cause error with "Color analysis".It wont work.

Comment: I am using it in my own App?

Comment: Shape fill doesn't accept linear gradient, it accepts string. Also, the constructor for linear gradient doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/react-native-china/react-native-ART-doc/blob/master/doc.md#lineargradient) is the doc of react-native ART module `LinearGradient` method usage.

AFAIK,it has some touble with Android platform,[here](https://productpains.com/post/react-native/lineargradient-art-for-android) is the problem and you can track it with productpains.

Answer (score 2):

Like Hylle pointed out, I wasn't able to get percentage offset to work in Android like iOS. All the colors are just evenly spaced. But here's a trick that worked for me:

```
let iosColors = { '.33': '#000', '.66': '#FFF' };
let androidColors = [ '#000', '#000', '#FFF', '#FFF' ];
```

or a more complex example:

```
let iosColors = { '.2': '#000', '.8': '#FFF' };
let androidColors = [ '#000', '#000', '#555', '#AAA', '#FFF', '#FFF' ];
```

Basically, if you have simple enough, fixed gradient values, you can 'precalculate' the evenly-spaced values you need to get the same percentage offset effect on Android.